# Do I need an attic exhaust fan?

Tags: attic, exhaust-fan, humidity

My attic is finished and has central air, but has a 2nd room that is unfinished with no duct work. We use it for storage. Currently it gets very hot and humid in that room in the summer, to the point that there is some minor mildew growth on the drywall in the unfinished room.

I got a quote for $650 to install an attic fan to help regulate the heat and humidity. I am worried that this might end up pulling air from inside my house and pull it out, making my AC work harder. The house is over 100 years old so it's gone this long without a fan and is fine.

Should I get the fan installed or would it just create another problem?

Comment: A) Define "finished" - drywall up usually indicates "finished" even if it's not painted. B) Where in the world do you live - different climates have different requirements. C) if your house is well sealed, your concern is valid, if it's not, then it's probably not a _huge_ issue. Just being 100 years old doesn't really tell us one way or the other - it could have had a fair bit of work done to it in those 100 years.

Comment: This question is opinion-based as it is. Attic fans should work in conjunction with static ventilation, such as soffit vents.

Answer (score 1):

I would only install an attic exhaust fan if you are positive that your attic is properly sealed and insulated from your home.

If not properly insulated (insulation taped and joints caulked), a new exhaust fan in your attic will draw air from your home.

Otherwise, an attic vent will help as long as ambient temperature/humidity are acceptable. The fan will ideally draw air only from exterior louvers, ridge vents (and shower/bath vents, if ductwork is not directed outside of attic.

Comment: I think your answer is worded poorly. The _conditioned space_ should be sealed and insulated, not the attic. The attic is, in effect, part of the universe _outside_ the home and cannot be sealed.

Answer (score -1):

If "unfinished" means open to the attic you should already have ventilation in the attic.   All my houses have had vents in the soffits (under the eaves) and then some version of vents or fans to force air out.  You need a way for outside air to get in and a way for it to get out.  Best practice where I live is ridge vents on the roof, but this typically requires replacing the roof.  **But** I've never seen drywall in an "unfinished room" - the drywall typically means it is finished.  If this is a room that is finished with drywall, you will need a way for air to get in or your exhaust fan might easily draw air from the rest of your finished house.

Your climate might be significantly different from mine, but I would be concerned that there is a water leak somewhere leading to mildew.  Hot temperatures don't create mold, they actively get rid of it, because the relative humidity will be very low when it is hot in the room.  Is this area above a shower or similar?

Comment: Ridge vents should not require a new roof.  You cut a slot at the peak and put the vent on.  I do not know any type of vents on most good roofs that need a new roof, unless the roof already needs replacing.  You might want different roofers.

Comment: @crip659, you are right, but these are generally installed along with new roofs.